# Rerun a Python script automatically following internal server error (500)?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I have a python script that connects to a remote server to download data.  Occasionally I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I have to manually re-run the script.  Is there any code I can add to the script itself that will restart it automatically if this happens, so I don't have to do it manually?  In case it matters, I'm using urrlib2 to access the web server.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

#### Edit:

I tried the answer posted below, but am now getting a JSON object error -- here's my function:

```
def get_response(url, query='', get_json=True):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(
             urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
             urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
             urllib2.ProxyHandler(
                {'https': 'http://u:pw@s:p',
                 'http': 'http://u:pw@s:p'}
    ))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    encoded = urllib.urlencode(query)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, encoded)
    if get_json:
        try:
            return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print '500 error'
            if e.getcode() == 500:
                get_response(url, query='', get_json=True)
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

#### Edit:

When I run print urllib2.urlopen(request).read() as the first line in the try block, I get:

```
{"token" : "1BgKWHBCyjviLz2skV2eI6RdHK4xi05Mq0CKcq_Ik3-15mpndnlodtSp6-SkOKVIHc8hBk_XwAIfdUurhubybZ8b4Yi176NNXgU75jD7HglQzFcG-wcEe4Ged8AGo_-dkAdVQ2ODf1ai-duxt5tJRQ..","expires" : 1432290875094,"ssl" : false}
{"currentVersion":10.3,"serviceDescription":"Dienst zur Erfassung von BaumschÃ¤den zur ErfÃ¼llung der Verkehrssicherungspflicht","hasVersionedData":false,"supportsDisconnectedEditing":false,"hasStaticData":false,"maxRecordCount":1000,"supportedQueryFormats":"JSON","capabilities":"Create,Delete,Query,Update,Editing,Extract,Sync","description":"Dienst zur Erfassung von BaumschÃ¤den im Rahmen der ErfÃ¼llung der Verkehrssicherungspflicht","copyrightText":"","spatialReference":{"wkid":25832,"latestWkid":25832},"initialExtent":{"xmin":348536.13803965045,"ymin":5660234.086535966,"xmax":405622.75221288018,"ymax":5696302.1586721111,"spatialReference":{"wkid":25832,"latestWkid":25832}},"fullExtent":{"xmin":344091.1291496334,"ymin":5640930.047927889,"xmax":410067.76110289729,"ymax":5712908.95763933,"spatialReference":{"wkid":25832,"latestWkid":25832}},"allowGeometryUpdates":true,"units":"esriMeters","size":507904,"syncEnabled":true,"syncCapabilities":{"supportsAsync":true,"supportsRegisteringExistingData":true,"supportsSyncDirectionControl":true,"supportsPerLayerSync":true,"supportsPerReplicaSync":true,"supportsSyncModelNone":true,"supportsRollbackOnFailure":true},"editorTrackingInfo":{"enableEditorTracking":true,"enableOwnershipAccessControl":false,"allowOthersToUpdate":true,"allowOthersToDelete":true},"xssPreventionInfo":{"xssPreventionEnabled":true,"xssPreventionRule":"InputOnly","xssInputRule":"rejectInvalid"},"layers":[{"id":0,"name":"Baumkontrolle AGS-online","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0},{"id":1,"name":"20110920-VSP-GewUnterh","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0},{"id":2,"name":"20110920-VSP-Talsp","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0},{"id":3,"name":"20130211-VSP-BuN_utm","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0},{"id":4,"name":"20130313-VSP-T3_Badestellen","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0},{"id":5,"name":"VSP_Strassen","parentLayerId":-1,"defaultVisibility":true,"subLayerIds":null,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0}],"tables":[]}
{"transportType":"esriTransportTypeUrl","responseUrl":"http://services1.arcgis.com/0cr41EdkajvOA232/ArcGIS/rest/services/Forstmobil/replicafiles/e598ff9192da40c98781a90151dc1101.zip"}
500 error
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link href='/ESRI.ArcGIS.SDS.REST.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel='SHORTCUT ICON' href='/favicon.ico'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  <meta name="keywords" content="ArcGIS REST Services Directory Root">
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" class="userTable">
<tr>
<td class="titlecell">ArcGIS REST Services Directory</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="navTable" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/0cr41EdkajvOA232/ArcGIS/rest/services">Home</a> > <a href="/0cr41EdkajvOA232/ArcGIS/rest/services">services</a> </td>
<td align="right">
<a href="http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/" target="_blank">API Reference</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="apiref">
<a href="?f=pjson" target="_blank">JSON</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class='restHeader'>
<h2>Home</h2>
</div>
<div class='restBody'>
<div class="restErrors">
Token Required<br/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This suggests the response isn't a valid JSON string. What do you get if you `print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()`?

Comment: What you have posted isn't a valid JSON string, hence the error. I suggest you look into the documentation for the service you are connecting to or open a new question as this now a new issue.

Comment: Back on topic, to catch all 500 errors you need to ensure all calls to `urlopen()` are wrapped in a try/except block. Meaning your last line `return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()` must also be in a try block.

Comment: If this worked for you please don't forget to except an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the error and then handle it yourself by recalling your script:

```
def main():
  try:
    # Your script
  except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.getcode() == 500:
      main()

main()
```